# Play Gif Once using Fresco Library

Tags: android, fresco

I am using the following code to play the gif, but here it keeps on repeating the gif play.

```
Uri uri;
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
    .setUri(uri)
    .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
    . // other setters
    .build();
mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```

How can i play it once?

Answer (score 7):

Well, I have not used fresco for GIF file but might be this one could help you out. Use below library for GIF file loading.
    [Refer this link](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)
 This is my code, and it works well:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GifImageView mGigImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mGigImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.mgif);

     GifDrawable gifDrawable = null;
     try {
          gifDrawable = new GifDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ani_1);
          gifDrawable.setLoopCount(1);
         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
     mGigImageView.setImageDrawable(gifDrawable);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already using this.. since the fresco support gif, i can get rid of this lib

Comment: fresco doesnt support playing gif once. awesome answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks you are great, after searching 2 days your solution work. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NaeemIbrahim: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Glide for GIF..It is better library.

Glide is quite similar to Picasso but this is much faster than Picasso.
Glide consumes less memory than Picasso.

What that Glide has but Picasso doesn't
An ability to load GIF Animation to a simple ImageView might be the most interesting feature of Glide. And yes, you can't do that with Picasso.

Some important links-
1. https://github.com/bumptech/glide 
2. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

You can also use the  **Ion** library to load the gif.
 Refer this link [click here](https://www.beginnersheap.com/creating-simple-splash-screen-android-animated-gif-image-example/)

Gradle dependencies for it:-

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

To load the gif from the drawable like below:-

```
ImageView imgView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Ion.with(imgView)
        .error(R.drawable.error_image)
        .animateGif(AnimateGifMode.ANIMATE)
        .load("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/" + R.drawable.loadingbh)
        .withBitmapInfo();
```

And load the Image from the **URL** like :-

```
Ion.with(imgView)
            .error(R.drawable.error_image)
            .animateGif(AnimateGifMode.ANIMATE)
            .load("https://www.beginnersheap.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/loading-BH.gif")  ///LOAD YOUR URL GIF
            .withBitmapInfo();
```

Comment: i am aware of this lib... i dont want to increase my size of the apk. i want to work with the existing lib i have in my app

Comment: How to play gif once with glide?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.splash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.exp.R;

public class SplashViewAnimation extends View {

    private Movie mMovie;
    private long mMovieStart;

    public SplashViewAnimation(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.coca_cola2); // Put your gif file here.. 
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is); 
    }

    public SplashViewAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.coca_cola2);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    public SplashViewAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrSet, defStyle);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.coca_cola2);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0x00000000);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) { // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }

        if(mMovie != null){              
            int dur = mMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0)
            {
                dur = 1000;
            }
            int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);

            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas,(int)((getWidth() - mMovie.width()) - getWidth()*.80),
                    (int)((getHeight() - (mMovie.height()-6)) - getHeight()*.10));

            invalidate();
        }
    }
    }
/// Use above code in main class :-

        SplashViewAnimation sp = new SplashViewAnimation(this);       
        FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);

        LayoutParams layoutParams = new     LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;          
        mainLayout.addView(sp,layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late reply. However, I couldn't find a correct answer after searching for over a couple of hours(I wanted to use only fresco and avoid adding another library for just one GIF). This could help someone like me searching for the answer. I could finally achieve it with the following workaround.

```
    ControllerListener controllerListener = new BaseControllerListener<ImageInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onFinalImageSet(
                        String id,
                        @Nullable ImageInfo imageInfo,
                        @Nullable final Animatable anim) {
                    if (anim != null) {
                        try {
//This is important to handle the loop. We are getting the field from class and //setting the loop count
                            Field field = AbstractAnimatedDrawable.class.getDeclaredField("mLoopCount");
                            field.setAccessible(true);
                            field.set(anim, 1);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        anim.start();
                    }
                }
            };

    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setUri(uri).setAutoPlayAnimations(false).setControllerListener(controllerListener)
                    // other setters
                    .build();
    simpleImageView.setController(controller);
```

Hope this helps.
Thank you.

Comment: AbstractAnimatedDrawable class not found.